# Modify string output for SQL statements

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to modify output like this `[SNO, text, SNAME, text, STATUS, number, CITY, text]`.
To something like this `(SNO text, SNAME, text, STATUS number, CITY, text)`

But the input I get after processing the first mentioned output with this code

```
String fieldsToTable ="(" + tableFields + ")";
fieldsToTable.replaceAll("[()]", "");
String modFieldsToTable = fieldsToTable.replace("\\,","");
System.out.println(modFieldsToTable);
```

I get this out as an output: `([SNO, text, SNAME, text, STATUS, number, CITY, text])`

I thing that I am not really grasping the concept of regex...

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
fieldsToTable = fieldsToTable.replace("[","(").replace("]",")");
```

Comment: I am sorry but the output still has to many commas :/ 
((SNO, text, SNAME, text, STATUS, number, CITY, text))

I think I can remove the extra brackets by looking through my code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
String fields = "(" + tableFields.substring(1, tableFields.length() - 1) + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String tableFields = "[SNO, text, SNAME, text, STATUS, number, CITY, text]";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String field : tableFields.split("[\\[\\] ,]")) {
        if (!field.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(field);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        sb.append(iterator.next());
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    sb.append(")");
    String modFieldsToTable = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(modFieldsToTable);
}
```

Comment: I get a cannot resolve method error on for (String field : tableFields.split("[\\[\\] ,]")) {. and split is marked in red. I don't understand why :(

Comment: Don't forget escape the \ with \\.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input `String tableFields = "[SNO, text, SNAME, text, STATUS, number, CITY, text]"`...

To remove the square brackets, try:

```
String fieldsToTable = tableFields.replace('[', '('); // replaces [ with (  
fieldsToTable = fieldsToTable.replace(']', ')');      // replaces ] with )
```

It is not clear when your commas should be removed. If you want to remove all commas, the code would be:

```
fieldsToTable = fieldsToTable.replaceAll(",", ""); // removes all commas
```

If you are just trying to remove the commas in those two specific cases, you can simply do:

```
fieldsToTable = fieldsToTable.replace("SNO,", "SNO");      // removes comma after SNO
fieldsToTable = fieldsToTable.replace("STATUS," "STATUS"); // removes comma after STATUS
```

Note that since the [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method returns the resulting String, you can improve the clarity of the code by chaining the three together.

```
String fieldsToTable = tableFields.replace('[', '(')
                                  .replace(']', ')')
                                  .replaceAll(",", "");
```

or

```
String fieldsToTable = tableFields.replace('[', '(')
                                  .replace(']', ')')
                                  .replace("SNO,", "SNO")
                                  .replace("STATUS," "STATUS");
```